# Python3 BeautifulSoup returning concatenated strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to pull a list of actors from this html once I find it

```
actors_anchor = soup.find('a', href = re.compile('Actor&p'))
parent_tag = actors_anchor.parent
next_td_tag = actors_anchor_parent.findNext('td')

next_td_tag

<font size="2">Wes Bentley<br><a href="/people/chart/
?view=Actor&amp;id=brycedallashoward.htm">Bryce Dallas Howard</a><br><a
href="/people/chart/?view=Actor&amp;id=robertredford.htm">Robert        
Redford</a><br><a href="/people/chart/ view=Actor&amp;id=karlurban.htm">Karl Urban</a></br></br></br></font>
```

The problem is that when I pull the text it returns a single string with no whitespace between names

```
print(next_td_tag.get_text())
'''this returns'''
'Wes BentleyBryce Dallas HowardRobert RedfordKarl Urban'
```

I need to get these names into a list where each name is separated like
    ['Wes Bentley','Bryce Dallas Howard','Robert Redford', 'Karl Urban']

any suggestions would be much obliged.

Comment: can't you use `find_all('a', ...)` and `for-loop` without `parent` and `findNext`?

Comment: Please elaborate. Thank you for the format editing this is my first post.

Comment: so the problem is that not all of the actor names are contained within an <a> tag many of the names in the html appear in between <br> tags when I use that method it does not allow me to obtain 'Wes Bentley'

Comment: @ChaceMcguyer yeah, addressed in the answer, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locate all `a` elements inside the found `td`:

```
[a.get_text() for a in next_td_tag.find_all('a')]
```

This though would not cover the "Wes Bentley" text which is hanging without an `a` element.

We can approach it differently and locate all the *text nodes* instead:

```
next_td_tag.find_all(text=True)
```

You might need to clean it up and remove the "empty" items:

```
texts = [text.strip().replace("\n", " ") for text in next_td_tag.find_all(text=True)]
texts = [text for text in texts if text]
print(texts)
```

Would print:

```
['Wes Bentley', 'Bryce Dallas Howard', 'Robert Redford', 'Karl Urban']
```

Comment: This has solved my problem. Quite simple now that I see it, your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stripped_strings` to get all strings as list

```
html = '''<td><font size="2">Wes Bentley<br><a href="/people/chart/
?view=Actor&amp;id=brycedallashoward.htm">Bryce Dallas Howard</a><br><a
href="/people/chart/?view=Actor&amp;id=robertredford.htm">Robert Redford</a><br><a href="/people/chart/ view=Actor&amp;id=karlurban.htm">Karl Urban</a></br></br></br></font></td>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

next_td_tag = soup.find('td')

print(list(next_td_tag.stripped_strings))
```

result

```
['Wes Bentley', 'Bryce Dallas Howard', 'Robert Redford', 'Karl Urban']
```

---

`stripped_strings` is generator so you can use it with `for`-loop or get all elements using `list()`

Comment: Ah, exactly, fits the problem perfectly!

Comment: @alecxe there is no white space at the head or tail, stripped_strings do noting here. and the answer's html code is modified, the '\n' is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

```
import bs4

html = '''<font size="2">Wes Bentley<br><a href="/people/chart/
?view=Actor&amp;id=brycedallashoward.htm">Bryce Dallas Howard</a><br><a
href="/people/chart/?view=Actor&amp;id=robertredford.htm">Robert        
Redford</a><br><a href="/people/chart/ view=Actor&amp;id=karlurban.htm">Karl Urban</a></br></br></br></font>'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

text = soup.get_text(separator='|') # concat the stings by separator 
# 'Wes Bentley|Bryce Dallas Howard|Robert        \nRedford|Karl Urban'
split_text = text.replace('        \n', '').split('|') # than split string in separator.
# ['Wes Bentley', 'Bryce Dallas Howard', 'RobertRedford', 'Karl Urban']

# do it one line 
list_text = soup.get_text(separator='|').replace('        \n', '').split('|')
```

or use string generator to avoid manually split string into list:

```
[i.replace('        \n', '') for i in soup.strings]
```